# Resume a stopped process through command line

Tags: linux, process, signals, kill

I've executed the following C code in Linux CentOS to create a process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    int main ()
    {
          int i = 0;

          while ( 1 )
          {
                printf ( "\nhello %d\n", i ++ );
                sleep ( 2 );
          }
    }
```

I've compiled it to `hello_count`. When I do `./hello_count`, The output is like this:

```
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
...
```

till I kill it.
I've stopped the execution using the following command

```
kill -s SIGSTOP 2956
```

When I do

```
ps -e
```

the process `2956 ./hello_count` is still listed.

Is there any command or any method to resume (not to restart) the process having process id 2956?

Also, when I stop the process, the command line shows:

```
[1]+ Stopped      ./hello_count
```

What does the `[1]+` in the above line mean?

Comment: For operations with threads use htop it's a good software and you can do almost anything with it. It's a command line programm. Try to search on google the types of signals you can send with "kill". I'm lazy right now, just giving some clues ^^

Answer (score 8):

- To continue a stopped process, that is resume use **kill -SIGCONT PID**
- Regd [1]+ that is bash way of handling jobs. For further information try **help jobs** from bash prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Shall I ask you one more doubt ?

Comment: I'm doing this in terminal. Suppose I stopped a process in one terminal window, and I want to resume the same process in another terminal window, what should I do ?

Comment: Ajish Alfred: In that case I think you'll have to start the command in `screen`.